# How can I prevent a **"java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input"** error code in Java?

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I was try to send data to the url http://mahavidyalay.in/AcademicDevelopment/ServerDemo/Led10.php?status=1 but it showing me error:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Cannot write output after reading input.

I think error is occurring because of line `int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();` And I don't 
 know how to solve this.

```
    URL Transmeter_Url = new URL(data);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) Transmeter_Url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",Contetn_Type);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Contetn-Length", Integer.toString(Post_Value.length()));
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en- 
    US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Get Response code:"+responseCode);

    System.out.println("Reached here 7");

    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

    System.out.println("Reached here 7");

    outputStream.write(Post_Value.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
```